# Can't instantiate NSURL with file path

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

When creating an NSURL with `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[@"~/Movies" stringByExpandingTildeInPath]]`, I get following error in the console:

`-[NSURL initWithScheme:host:path:]: path file:/localhost/Users/michael is not absolute.`

It worked while compiling in Debug mode, this problem occured only after switching to Release.

EDIT: Just to clarify, I get the error message at run time when the NSURL object is initialized, not while building.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code needs to look like:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[@"~/Movies" stringByExpandingTildeInPath]];
```

Looks to me like you are missing the @"" that needs to surround '~/Movies'.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I do have it in my code though, I just didn't copy paste it, and forgot the @"" when posting here.

Comment: it would have given a compiler warning and that case

Answer (score 1):

works fine here ...

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[@"~/Movies" stringByExpandingTildeInPath]];
 NSLog(@"url: %@", url);
```

BUT
is your app sandboxed in release mode? That could explain this